# Why does my Browser open another Browser?

Tags: android, browser

I am creating an Android application to work as a simple browser. The user enters a web address and then clicks a button. After this, the application should the website in the WebView. However, after the button is clicked, a notification pops up asking me to choose a browser to complete my action. [The options in the pop up are my default browser, mozilla, etc.]

However, I do not want to use any of them. What should I do ?

This is my .java file:

```
package com.example.all_in_one;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class SimpleBrowser extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    WebView myBrowser;
    EditText URLaddress;
    Button Go;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.simple_browser);

        myBrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WV);
        URLaddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.webaddress);
        Go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go);
        Go.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.go:
            String address = URLaddress.getText().toString();
            myBrowser.loadUrl("http://" + address);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LL1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:weightSum="5" >
        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/webaddress"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/go"
            android:text="Go"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <WebView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/WV"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LL1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have added the Internet permission in my Manifest file.

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: downvoted without adding a comment :(

Comment: Did u checked my answer ? Is it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the `WebViewClient` class object to `browser.setWebViewClient(new BrowserClient())` to open the links in the webview.

```
private class BrowserClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.d(tag, "shouldOverrideUrlLoading");
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and in your onCreate() call like this

```
myBrowser.setWebViewClient(new BrowserClient());
```

Comment: what should I add in place of "tag" ?

Comment: Its just for printing purpose you can remove that line